# Разбор массива объектов на php

Tags: массивы, php, объекты

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть массив объектов вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tbl2 Object
        (
            [tableFields:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [some_field] => test1
                    [tables] => Tbl Object
                        (
                            [tableFields:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [name] => TEST INSERT 2
                                    [text] => выборка по id=4
                                    [fk_tbl2] => 1
                                )
                        )

                )
        )

[1] => Tbl2 Object
    (
        [tableFields:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [some_field] => test2
                [tables] => Tbl Object
                    (
                        [tableFields:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [name] => TEST8
                                [text] => выборка по id=2
                                [fk_tbl2] => 2
                            )
                    )

            )
    )

[2] => Tbl2 Object
    (
        [tableFields:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [some_field] => test2
                [tables] => Tbl Object
                    (
                        [tableFields:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [name] => TEST INSERT
                                [text] => 
                                [fk_tbl2] => 2
                            )
                    )

            )
    )

  )
```

В примере три объекта Tbl2, из них два повторяются (с id=2) из-за того, что они содержат разные подобъекты Tbl. Никак не могу привести массив к следующему виду:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tbl2 Object
        (
            [tableFields:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [some_field] => test1
                    [tables] => Tbl Object
                        (
                            [tableFields:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [name] => TEST INSERT 2
                                    [text] => выборка по id=4
                                    [fk_tbl2] => 1
                                )
                        )

                )
        )

[1] => Tbl2 Object
    (
        [tableFields:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [some_field] => test2
                [tables] => Array (
                    [0] => Tbl Object
                    (
                        [tableFields:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [name] => TEST8
                                [text] => выборка по id=2
                                [fk_tbl2] => 2
                            )
                    ),
                    [1] => Tbl Object
                    (
                        [tableFields:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [name] => TEST INSERT
                                [text] => 
                                [fk_tbl2] => 2
                            )
                    )

            )
    )
  )
```

Т.е., получать ДВА объекта Tbl2, но тот, что с id=2 должен содержать массив объектов Tbl.

Comment: Вам, скорее всего, придется самостоятельно писать функционал. Нужны будут:
1. Метод для сравнения объектов
2. Метод для сравнения/слияния вложенных объектов
3. Метод для объединения. Как вариант, можно использовать `array_filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);
```

или так

```
$obj_merged = (object) array_merge_recursive((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);
```

Comment: [`array_merge_recursive`][1] ничего не даст - здесь ключи числовые.

Скорее всего вам понадобится определить свою функцию слияния

  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php